How to use Python-Docx to extract the paragraphs in between a heading and a table
I am using Python-docx to work with several large word documents to extract headings, paragraphs and table contents and put them into Excel.  The code is working well EXCEPT when there are multiple paragraphs in between the heading and the table.  I have dug through the documentation and looked on Google for a solution, without luck.
When the Word contents look like this, my code works fine.

First paragraph is text with heading style 1 that starts with '['
Second paragraph is 'normal' text
Table with multiple fields of text

When the Word contents look like this, my code does not work as desired.  The code puts the second, third and Fourth paragraphs in the wrong place.

First paragraph is text with heading style 1 that starts with '['
Second paragraph is 'normal' text
Third paragraph is 'normal' text
Fourth paragraph is 'normal' text
Table with multiple fields of text

What I want is:

First paragraph is text with heading style 1 that starts with '[' writes to my list of headings
Lump these paragraphs into one chunk of text
2) Second paragraph is 'normal' text
3) Third paragraph is 'normal' text
4) Fourth paragraph is 'normal' text
Table with multiple fields of text write to my linedata list which works just fine

Here is the code snippet that reads in the headings and paragraphs.
#######################################################################################################
# Define the function that will read in the headings from the Word document
def iter_headings(paragraphs):
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
        if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading') and paragraph.text.startswith('['):
            Req_Name.append(paragraph.text)
    return Req_Name

#######################################################################################################
# Define the function that will read in the paragraph text from the Word document
def iter_text(paragraphs):
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
        if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Normal') and paragraph.text:
            Req_Text.append(paragraph.text)
    return Req_Text

#######################################################################################################

for paragraph in iter_headings(doc.paragraphs):
    Req_Name 

Req_Name=pd.DataFrame(Req_Name)
Req_Name.to_excel('req_name.xlsx') 

# # Read in the requirement text
for paragraph in iter_text(doc.paragraphs):
    Req_Text         

Req_Name=pd.DataFrame(Req_Name)

# Read in the tabular data from word
for i in range(0, tableCount):  
    table = doc.tables[i]  
    if table.cell(0, 0).text != 'Rationale': continue
    print('i = ', i)
    reqCount=reqCount+1


    # Extract cell contents
    Rationale = table.cell(0, 1).text
    Crit_Cat = table.cell(1, 1).text
    Defining = table.cell(2, 1).text 
    Complying = table.cell(3, 1).text 
    Conflicting = table.cell(4, 1).text
    Valid_Strat = table.cell(5, 1).text
    Valid_Result = table.cell(6, 1).text
    Valid_Status = table.cell(7, 1).text
    Verify_Strat = table.cell(8, 1).text
    Verify_Result = table.cell(9, 1).text
    Verify_Status = table.cell(10, 1).text

    lineData=(Rationale, Crit_Cat, Defining, Complying, Conflicting, Valid_Strat, 
                               Valid_Result, Valid_Status, Verify_Strat, Verify_Strat, Verify_Result, Verify_Status)

I think that I need to detect when the table starts and then lump all the paragraphs between the heading the table start into one chunk of text, but I can't figure out how to detect the start of the table.
How far off base am I and is there an easier way??

I am not sure if your code can process the elements of the document in the very order they appear.
I use this approach (of course the print()s are just placeholders for the stuff you need to do):
import docx

# Iterate over the document and process paragraphs and tables
doc = docx.Document('the_document.docx')
for child in doc.iter_inner_content():
    if isinstance(child, docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph):
        if child.style.name.startswith('Heading'):
            print('Header:', child.text)
        elif child.style.name == 'Normal':
            print('Normal:', child.text)

    elif isinstance(child, docx.table.Table):
            print('table:', child)


dave9000 - Thanks for the help!  I had never heard of the 'child' functionality before.  thanks again!
